# setting permissions and allowing access based on user actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, controller, permissions

I would like a reference or an explanation or even some advice on how to find out about what im asking.

How can I set permissions for users to have access to a controller based on an activity that they have completed. For Example a user needs to have a paypal account to access a controller/page.  Another example is if a user has a rating of 2.5 or above out of 5 and is allowed to set prices for their services.  Another example is like how stack overflow works where they have a point system and when you reach a certain amount of points you can comment or answer questions or add a + to an asked question/answer.

Comment: I would recommend using cancancan gem for this. See [docs](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan). If you need more help feel free to reply here

Comment: The [Pundit](https://github.com/elabs/pundit) gem is what you need.

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: No need for a gem @mysmallidea. You can achieve what you need by creating a callback action such as a `before_filter` in the specific controller and set the requirements to access the controller in the `before_filter` method.

Comment: i looked up cancan but am not sure how to use it based on if a user has a 2.5 rating.  And i havent looked up pundit yet.. is there a good tutorial on something similar to what im doing? Im also want to allow a user to use a controller if they are setup with paypal..

Comment: @MichaelLombardo the Pundit readme is pretty thorough and a great place to start.

Comment: @Cyzanfar absolutely could be done without gem. For many projects though Pundit is a great choice - Pundit classes are plain old Ruby objects and there is no complicated DSL, so I find that it's often easier to use Pundit policies than to roll my own with callbacks or other methods. Callbacks, as you suggest, can be a good choice depending on your project.

Comment: I don't know why some people like gems so much, I avoid using gems whenever I can and for what's being asked I would say that a simple `before_action` is more than enough

Comment: ill look into the `before_action` as well to see!! thanks!!